How do I close a modal window inside a form without sending data to the server and prevent the page from reloading?
I have a web with javaee and primefaces, and I have bootstrap integrated to the project.
I know that with p:dialog I can perform the same behavior as a bootstrap modal window, but I implemented the adminlte plugin and the p:dialog is not displayed as a modal window.
The bootstrap modal window works fine but when it is inside a form it reloads the page as if it was sending data to the server, I don't want that.
How can I make it just close the modal and that's it?
I have tried to use dispose(), hide(), but then it doesn't open again.
    <h:form id="frm_Dialogo">
        
        <div class="modal fade show" id="dlg_Dialogo1">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="background:#E1EFF8">
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{ogeneralvista.tituloModal}" styleClass="tituloLetra" style="font-size:16px;"></p:outputLabel>
                        <button class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                        <h:commandLink onclick="return cerrarModal();" styleClass="btn-close" />
                        <p:commandButton styleClass="btn-close" action="#{ogeneralvista.cierraEjecutaConsulta()}" update="frm_Dialogo"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </h:form>



... but I implemented the adminlte plugin and the p:dialog is not displayed as a modal window ...

You could use an ApplicationFactory with an ApplicationWrapper where you override createComponent like:
@Override
public UIComponent createComponent(FacesContext context, String componentType, String rendererType) {
    UIComponent component = super.createComponent(context, componentType, rendererType);

    if (component instanceof Dialog) {
        Dialog dialog = (Dialog) component;
        dialog.setModal(true);
    }

    return component;
}

This will create all the dialogs as modal.
See https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/core/globalattributes
